# OptaPlanner - is there a way to trigger code at each Move in CH phase?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm currently using OptaPlanner 6.2.0 but can update if it can help.

I need to keep some data of chaining between variables and entities outside the planner, as well as some precalculated data and I need a way to update it after each move but before the rules are fired. I use that data when check the rules. I know it's a hacky way but there are complex rules which need separate data storing, can't think of the way to avoid it. Also this way the Planner has shown good performance.

So the thing is I need a way to trigger some code on each move which would update that separately stored data with the changes from current move, before the rules are applied for this move and decision about how good is the move is taken (because the rules address that data), so in fact before the score for this move gets recalculated.  On Local Search phase it's pretty simple because all of my moves are custom, so I can do it inside of doMove. But I really need to do the same thing in CH phase.

I'm aware that we can't change move type to custom in CH phase. I also find it very difficult to implement a full analogue of CH phase in CustomPhaseCommand for this little change. Removing CH phase and replacing it with simple custom phase reduces the quality of allocation for this specific task significantly even thought I had an example where it worked better without CH at all. I've also tried adding PhaseLifecycleListener to my Solver but it only listens to steps and phases, not to separate moves. The closest effort so far was implementing a VariableListener which indeed happens to fire beforeVariableChanged, afterVariableChanged at each move, even on CH phase. But in beforeVariableChanged I can only see the old variable, not the new one (I need both to update my data), and afterVariableChanged seems to fire AFTER the rules where fired and checked so it's useless to update the data in this method (by the way how do shadow variables get updated then on CH phase usually? I thought it should fire after, update the shadow variables there and then recheck the rules with updated shadow variables?)

I also tried to look at the chaining but I'm not sure it can fully cover my complex case with storing data separately and using it in rules...

So is there a way to correctly update my structure at each CH move? Or is there a simple way to handle the complex data dependencies other than moving it to separate structure outside of Planner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shadow variables maybe? See docs.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Hello. I found out why VariableListener was not always working for me to update the data and then recalculating after, so currently updating my separate structure in VariableListener works for me in CH phase. The reason I do these tricks instead of using classic Shadow Variables is the structure and rules build upon it are both pretty complex, I'm not sure that classic Shadow Variables are flexible enough for this. It would also require a lot of efforts to change the current model for it, but you're right, it's worth a try at some point.. Thanks for the answer!